# which log traces in CQ5.6.1 if the KEY certificate( for SSO ),node has been deleted from CRX repository

Tags: aem

We are using Adobe CQ5.6.1 to build a site. and we have used KEY certificate for SSO process. Somehow the node KEY (/etc/key)from CRX got deleted and we are unable to trace that.
Could someone please help us to trace where we can find the logs which states the deletion of  this node.

Response will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance !